# Xamarin Forms: handle multiple item per row

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms i want show multiple image (2) in a row: this is an example of what i'd like to do:

[image]

In many Q&A i've seen the use of XLabs gridview but the project is no longer maintained.

I think that i can create a custom cell with a stacklayout inside a row but the recycle policy work? And how can i handle the item tapped if i have two column per row?

Thanks

Comment: On iOS you really want a `UICollectionView` and on Android a `RecyclerView` using a `GridLayoutManager`, at least in terms of UI performance and memory considerations, Personally I would *not* recommend using a `StackLayout` in this UI design, there are 3rd-party options available (paid and OSS-based) that support the "proper" native views within Forms... google is your friend ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Alessandros answer should work, but if you want to roll something yourself without any third party controls, keep reading:

Recycling will still work if you use a Custom `ViewCell`. So I would suggest doing that and adding two items in a custom model and render them in one cell at a time.

Now for handling taps: Override the `ItemSelected` event on your `ListView` and set the `ListView.SelectedItem` to null. Then inside your custom `ViewCell`, add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to each of the separate models. One thing to note, is that the `Command` on your `TapGestureRecognizer` will bind to your individual list item, so you need to set it relative to the `BindingContext` of the `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ...>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal>
                <Image ...>
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView}, Path=BindingContext.Item1Command}"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <Image ...>
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyListView}, Path=BindingContext.Item2Command}"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers
                </Image>
            </StackLayout>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look to this [FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView).
I have never used it but sounds good.

```
<flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
            XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
```